# Llave esterna de tipo serial se auto-genera al hacer insert

Tags: java, sql, base-de-datos, postgresql

Tengo una tabla **"clients"**:

```
CREATE TABLE clients
(
  id serial NOT NULL,
  name character(25),
  user_id serial NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT "Client_pkey" PRIMARY KEY (id),
  CONSTRAINT clients_id_key UNIQUE (id)
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
ALTER TABLE clients
  OWNER TO postgres;
```

Otra tabla **"users"**:

```
    CREATE TABLE users
    (
      id serial NOT NULL,
      name character(20),
      surname character(20),
      password character(15),
      admin boolean,
      CONSTRAINT users_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
      CONSTRAINT users_id_key UNIQUE (id)
    )
    WITH (
      OIDS=FALSE
    );
    ALTER TABLE users
      OWNER TO postgres;
```

El problema es el siguiente:

Cuando hago un **Insert(id,name)** en la tabla *clients(sin user_id)*, en la columna **user_id** se auto-genera un valor automaticamente, lo cual no quiero que pase, quiero que user_id se quede en **null/sin valor**, y solo se inserte id y name.

Metodo para hacer el **Insert**:

```
private final Connection conn = ConnectToDatabase.createConnection();
    private final String SQL_CREATE_CLIENT = "INSERT INTO clients (id, name) VALUES (?, ?)";

public void createClient(Client client) {
        try (PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(SQL_CREATE_CLIENT, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS)) {
            pstmt.setInt(1, client.getId());
            pstmt.setString(2, client.getName());
            pstmt.executeUpdate();
            try (ResultSet generatedKeys = pstmt.getGeneratedKeys()) {
                if (generatedKeys.next()) {
                    client.setId(generatedKeys.getInt(1));
                }
            }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

La relación entre las 2 tablas es esta:

1. Un user tiene muchos clients.
2. Un client tiene un solo user.

Comment: No entenido muy bien, en el titulo pone cuando haces el update y despues dices cuando haces el insert. En cualquier caso el tipo SERIAL es un alias para BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT UNIQUE por lo cual debes cambiarle el tipo

Comment: Me equivoque con el titulo, quería decir "al hacer insert"

Comment: No pasa nada era solo para que la cambies, asi para no liarnos. Prueba lo que dije en el anterior comentario, haber si te funcion.

Comment: Vale, me imagino que no tengo que ponerlo como NOT NULL, ya que user_id puede ser nullo.

Comment: Listo, funciona gracias.

Comment: Lo añado como respuesta, por si a alguien le pasa algo por el estilo.